# sencha build giving error stbuild exited with non-zero code : 7

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

I wanted to create .apk file of my sencha application so I executed below command

sencha package build packager.json

but when I executed above command,it generates error as given below.

'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
""D:/Android/AndroidSDKr15\tools\android" create project --target android-16 --name chartDemoApp --activity STActivity --path "../build/" --package triumphsys. mobility.chartDemoApp"
Could not run ant with error: 1
Failed to package application

[ERR]           stbuild exited with non-zero code : 7

even I have attached my [command prompt here](http://i47.tinypic.com/r2krvq.png) and [packager.json](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/73250761/packager.json) here.

please help me to resolve it.

Comment: could someone reply to my question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by uninstalling "C:\Program files\Sencha Cmd" and again re-installing it at "C:\Sencha" without any spaces in folder name. and it worked for me.